# is it useful to use index when the number of selects equals the number of inserts?

Tags: database, indexing

suppose I have a table `Transaction` and there is a column `transactionId` each time I insert a row I check that `transactionId` is unique by selecting from the database, in most cases it is unique, the second thing I do is to insert the new row.
I know that using index on this column will speed the search for its uniqueness, but also will slow the writes.
my question is: does the time I gain when searching by adding this index is equal to the time that I lost by the same index when writing, considering that the number of writes is equal to the number of selects.

Answer (score 0):

why yes if the db is huge then the search time will dominate the insert time for a single item.